# Changing point className in Highcharts Gantt

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-gantt

The below seems to be a bug, but I don't know what the work around is?

**Expected behavior:**
The className for a data point in highcharts Gantt is not changed during update.

**Actual behavior:**
The className stays the same as its original set.

**Live demo with steps to reproduce:**

https://jsfiddle.net/gd5hswbv/

Clicking on the button (Change color) updates the first data point with a new class, color, and y value.
The y value changes and the color changes (as noted by the tooltip border), but the class (and thus the fill) does not.

Even adding chart.redraw() doesn't seem to help.

**JS Code from fiddle:**

```
let chart = Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Class update'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickPixelInterval: 70
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        grid: {
            enabled: true,
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            columns: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Project'
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }]
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%e %b %Y, %H:%M'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        data: [{
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 18, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            name: 'Start prototype',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 0,
            className: "color-purple",
            color: "green"
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 20, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 24, 16),
            name: 'Develop',
            assignee: 'Michaels',
            y: 1
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            name: 'Prototype done',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 2
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 27, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 3, 16),
            name: 'Test prototype',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 3
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 23, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 15, 16),
            name: 'Run acceptance tests',
            assignee: 'Halliburton',
            y: 4
        }]
    }],

    exporting: {
        sourceWidth: 1000
    }
});

$('#color').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        series: {
        data: [{
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 18, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            name: 'Start prototype',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 2,
            className: "color-red",
            color: "red"
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 20, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 24, 16),
            name: 'Develop',
            assignee: 'Michaels',
            y: 1
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            name: 'Prototype done',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 2
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 27, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 3, 16),
            name: 'Test prototype',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 3
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 23, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 15, 16),
            name: 'Run acceptance tests',
            assignee: 'Halliburton',
            y: 4
        }]
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that **className** feature can be defined for general series options, not in particular data object - API: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.className

I think that a better solution, in this case, is using only the inline styling - that changes also the tooltip border color.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w9j6mLac/

```
let chart = Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {

    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',

    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        data: [{
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 18, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            name: 'Start prototype',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 0,
            color: 'purple'
        }, { ... } ]
    }],
});

$('#color').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        series: {
        data: [{
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 18, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            name: 'Start prototype',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 2,
            color: 'red'
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 20, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 24, 16),
            name: 'Develop',
            assignee: 'Michaels',
            y: 1
        }, { ... }]
      }
    }, true, true, true);
});
```

Comment: That's not the prefered solution since, in my application, I'm using styled mode (an easy way to get the patterns and colors for each point). I did not include in the example since I was expecting the className to work regardless.

Your answer suggests you can't change the colors while in styled mode.

Comment: That's this `className` seems to work for data on initial load, but it is not planned and documented feature - not sure if it is a bug if it wasn't planned to implement. However, if you need this kind of solution you can 'force' chart to do a 'hard' redraw by adding additional data object, which is empty. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/45j7vqnr/ when data.length is the same chart just do some animation changes, but when the length is different deeper changes are triggered.